# Moving nodes down using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

After puting my question up here, I managed to move a node up ([Moving nodes up using XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26121407/moving-nodes-up-using-xslt)). After this I thought I understood it so I tried the opposite to move a node down. Didn't work. This is what I did:

My input data is called DEBTORS.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<eExact xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="eExact-Schema.xsd">
<Accounts>
 <Account code="                 001" status="A" type="C">
  <Name>Name</Name>
  <Contacts>
   <Contact default="1" gender="M" status="A">
    <Note>Patient: 1</Note>
    <FirstName></FirstName>
    <Addresses>
     <Address type="D" desc="">
      <AddressLine1>Street</AddressLine1>
      <AddressLine2></AddressLine2>
      <AddressLine3></AddressLine3>
      <PostalCode>0000 AA</PostalCode>
      <City>&apos;City</City>
      <Country code="NL"/>
      <Phone></Phone>
      <Fax></Fax>
     </Address>
     </Addresses>
    <Language code="NL"/>
    <JobDescription>--</JobDescription>
    <Phone></Phone>
    <PhoneExt></PhoneExt>
    <Fax></Fax>
    <Mobile></Mobile>
    <Email></Email>
    <WebAccess>0</WebAccess>
     </Contact>
  </Contacts>
    <Debtor number="   1" code="                 1">
   <Currency code="EUR"/>
   </Debtor>
   </Account>
</Accounts>
</eExact>
```

My XSL called Test2.xsl

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<!-- Indentation in XSL -->
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<!-- Removing blank lines in XSL -->
<xsl:strip-space  elements="*"/>

<!-- Identity rule -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

<!-- special rules ... -->
    <xsl:template match="Account">
        <xsl:copy>
          <!-- exclude Name -->
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()[not(self::Name)]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Contacts">
    <xsl:copy>
        <!-- include Name -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node() | Contact/Name"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Wanted** output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<eExact xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="eExact-Schema.xsd">
<Accounts>
 <Account code="                 001" status="A" type="C">
  <Contacts>
   <Contact default="1" gender="M" status="A">
    <Name>Name</Name>
    <Note>Patient: 1</Note>
    <FirstName></FirstName>
    <Addresses>
     <Address type="D" desc="">
      <AddressLine1>Street</AddressLine1>
      <AddressLine2></AddressLine2>
      <AddressLine3></AddressLine3>
      <PostalCode>0000 AA</PostalCode>
      <City>&apos;City</City>
      <Country code="NL"/>
      <Phone></Phone>
      <Fax></Fax>
     </Address>
     </Addresses>
    <Language code="NL"/>
    <JobDescription>--</JobDescription>
    <Phone></Phone>
    <PhoneExt></PhoneExt>
    <Fax></Fax>
    <Mobile></Mobile>
    <Email></Email>
    <WebAccess>0</WebAccess>
     </Contact>
  </Contacts>
    <Debtor number="   1" code="                 1">
   <Currency code="EUR"/>
   </Debtor>
   </Account>
</Accounts>
</eExact>
```

My problem is that with my XSL the node "Name" is deleted, but doesn't come back as a child of contact. Hope someone will help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I'd recommend a few changes:**

1. To suppress `Name`, add a template rule that matches it but does
   nothing.
2. To add `Name` to `Contact`, add a template rule that matches `Contact` and
   copies as usual but also inserts `Name`.
3. Eliminate the template currently matching `Contacts` (plural); the
   general identity rule can handle that fine.

**Here's your complete stylesheet updated as mentioned:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <!-- Indentation in XSL -->
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" omit-xml-declaration="yes"
              encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

  <!-- Removing blank lines in XSL -->
  <xsl:strip-space  elements="*"/>

  <!-- Identity rule -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- special rules ... -->
  <xsl:template match="Name"/>

  <xsl:template match="Contact">
    <xsl:copy>
      <!-- include Name -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <Name><xsl:value-of select="../../Name"/></Name>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Given your sample input XML, the above XSLT produces the requested output XML:**

```
<eExact xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="eExact-Schema.xsd">
   <Accounts>
      <Account code="                 001" status="A" type="C">
         <Contacts>
            <Contact default="1" gender="M" status="A">
               <Name>Name</Name>
               <Note>Patient: 1</Note>
               <FirstName/>
               <Addresses>
                  <Address type="D" desc="">
                     <AddressLine1>Street</AddressLine1>
                     <AddressLine2/>
                     <AddressLine3/>
                     <PostalCode>0000 AA</PostalCode>
                     <City>'City</City>
                     <Country code="NL"/>
                     <Phone/>
                     <Fax/>
                  </Address>
               </Addresses>
               <Language code="NL"/>
               <JobDescription>--</JobDescription>
               <Phone/>
               <PhoneExt/>
               <Fax/>
               <Mobile/>
               <Email/>
               <WebAccess>0</WebAccess>
            </Contact>
         </Contacts>
         <Debtor number="   1" code="                 1">
            <Currency code="EUR"/>
         </Debtor>
      </Account>
   </Accounts>
</eExact>
```